# How do I restore internet access to my devices with the iptables service running and ip forwarding enabled?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, forwarding

I use my laptop's hotspot with Ubuntu Linux for internet on my phone and entertainment devices.

When I install the Linux Firewall iptables (ip forwarding enabled) by inputting in terminal:

**sudo apt-get install iptables iptables-persistent**

**sudo service iptables start**

All of my other devices lose internet connection from my hotspot(my laptop)

Even if I don't input any rules into the iptables, I still lose internet connection on the devices connected to my hotspot. **My laptop still has internet connection.**

How do I keep my internet connection on my devices while still having the iptables service **running** and ip forwarding **enabled**?

Comment: Maybe the iptables cancel the hotspot. Try using internet access(your computer is using) for all of your devices instead of the hotspot from your laptop.

Comment: I need to connect my other devices to my laptops's wifi hotspot to change firewall settings for those devices using iptables. The hotspot is still active, but there is no internet access for devices connected through hotspot when iptables service is running.

Comment: Oh, that pretty weird. Sorry, I have no ideas.

Comment: How do you know ip forwarding has been turned on? And how do you know iptables is doing anything to protect the laptop - other then turning off ip forwarding? You still have to configure iptables. Maybe it's just a routing problem between the WIFI default route and the LAN default route.  It's extremely unlikely you'll be able to install iptables on your other devices unless they are running linux. But then your iptables become more complicated. I've never setup a hotspot so I can't help you. I suggest you install a proxy.